# Removing everything after a string in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a bunch of image file names that i uploaded to wordpress and want to change the file names using sql in phpmyadmin. The files are as such:
text-text-text-328x328.jpg
text-text-590x236.jpg
text-text-text-text-150x150.jpg
text-569x348.jpg

tex-text-text.jpg

So i want to remove the file in the title. The only footprint i can thing of is removing string after - plus a number

I know how to remove everything after - :

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyText = LEFT(MyText, CHARINDEX('-', MyText) - 1)
WHERE CHARINDEX(';', MyText) > 0
```

Just not sure how to remove everything after - and a number.

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose I can just run through the code above 10 times, sql '-1', '2', '3', '4', etc..

Comment: You can add a REGEX condition in the WHERE clause matching something like `.*-\d+x\d+\.jpg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  concat(
    substr(name, 1, length(name) - length(substring_index(name,'-',-1)) - 1),
    '.',
    substring_index(name, '.', -1)
  ) as newname
FROM 0_a
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot! Worked great :)